# Cannot use import statement outside a module in Next.js while using Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, next.js

So whenever I am using redux-toolkit with any of the components, it throws me an error that I can't use an import statement outside. I have tried changing my package.  json file also to type='module'

Error in terminal

```
import Provider from './components/Provider';
location of error :- \node_modules\react-redux\es\exports.js
```

used only basic redux like this

```
const shownDown = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.navbar.isShown);
  const infoDown = useSelector(
    (state: RootState) => state.navbar.isUsefulInfoShown
  );
```

Any help would be appreciate other wise have to shift back to CRA

Comment: Hi, you prolly have messed up store setup, would be good if you post that, also note that you need react-redux installed not only redux toolkit

Comment: this is not my first time using redux-toolkit so I know how it works redux is working fine as it should be. The error occurs only when I add to the final component like to index file